# replace string with a db function in php

Tags: php, replace

I want to replace a string with database function if it exists. I am using `str_replace` in following way but it doesn't work for me, this is returning `$numOne` as it was.

```
function stringreplace($multiple,$numOne){
    $multiple = Multiply;
    $numOne = a_b_cMultiply;
    str_replace($multiple, "abcdfgh('','')::numeric", $numOne);
    return $numOne;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the before and after of the value you want to process? :)

Comment: this is my complete code for this

Comment: I can't seem to understand your code? What is Multiply? a_b_cMultiply?

Comment: Multiply is a simple string and a_b_cMultiply is a formula. Actually i want if a_b_cMultiply comes it should be replaced by a_b_cabcdfgh('','')

Comment: Check the answer of @Rahul :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not correct as you are not storing the result anywhere and also you are returning $numOne which contains the old value . Use this code:

```
function stringreplace($multiple,$numOne){
$multiple='Multiply';
 $numOne='a_b_cMultiply';
 $num_one = str_replace($multiple,"abcdfgh('','')::numeric",$numOne);
return $num_one;
}
```

Comment: i got this. and what if i want to add operator like * between a_b_c*abcdgfh('','')

Comment: Well in that case change  `$numOne='a_b_cMultiply'` to  `$numOne='a_b_c*Multiply'`